# Python Cognititve toolkit, utils dll not found

Tags: python, cntk

I am trying to use the examples in Cognitive toolkit in python but I received this error and I cannot solve it:

> DLL not found

in this line:

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
   from utils2_win64.cython_bbox import bbox_overlaps
else:
    from .utils3_win64.cython_bbox import bbox_overlaps
```

but in the project, I have the library like in the photo

[image]

I receive this error in : imdb.py file.

how can I fix it? and please a little explanation.

CNTK version: CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only

Path: C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only

Anocanda path:C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64

OS: windows 10 with code project.

to lunch Python normally I use this path:

C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35

Comment: More information will help. Version of CNTK.  Type of CNTK installation. OS used.  IDE used.  How was the IDE launched.  value of PYTHON_PATH and PATH environment variables.

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: what does utils3_win64 means?

Comment: From your python environment in which you installed CNTK, what happen when you type: "import cntk"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was with the Python version I am using. 
I was using Python 3.5 and it is not supported by CNTK yet.

I changed the version to Python 3.4 and it works correctly.

To change the version you can write directly in CMD:

> conda create --name cntk python=3.4.3 numpy scipy